# Is this possible? Use jQuery to modify a string from inside a style tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Let's say you have,

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jQuery.js"></script>
        <style>
            html { ... }
            body { background: black }
        </style>
    </head>
<body>

...

</body>
</html>
```

I  know it's possible to use jQuery like `$("body").css("background", "white")` but is it possible to use jQuery to target and replace the `black` text to `white` inside the `style` tag?

I don't want to simply append `body { background: white }`, like `$("style").append("body { background: white}")` and I don't want to use `.html` because I don't want to rewrite the entire tag, **I want to modify a string from inside the `style` tag**. Is this possible?

Thanks!

(If you're going to mark this as a duplicate, please comment or respond how whatever inferred method works, please.)

Comment: lots of "i don't want to" with no real reason given why not

Comment: Curious as to the limits of jQuery. This would be really helpful. Prefer to use best of jQuery, if available.

Comment: what's wrong with using html() or text() on style tag? `$("style").text(function(_, existing){ return existing.replace('black','white'); })`. Appending whole rule seems simplest though

Comment: Good question. `.html()` will rewrite all of `<style>` and thus trash other rules. `.append()` and `.text()` would simply append the `<style>` tag (I'm pretty sure). What I want to do is dynamically change the `<style>` tag without appending it.

Comment: but what's wrong with appending?

Comment: Not much, just cosmetics. But my interest is dynamically altering the CSS without adding extraneous rules.

Comment: have to parse the string then like I did above using `replace()`. As far as DOM is concerned it is all text. Again appending rule is simplest and safest. Not sure why you would worry about extraneous rules

Comment: Oh, totally overlooked your answer. Didn't get that you provided a parser function, thanks! Yeah, that's awesome.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery selectors are based off the CSS selector syntax. That is the ID, Classes, and HTML display tags. I believe he answer to your question is no.

Comment: That's what I feared. Can I do something like `$("style"."black").text("white")`? (As an example of the pseudo code.

Comment: What element are you are you trying to change the text to? If it were a paragraph you would do. $('p').css('color','white')

Comment: It's OK, thanks! :)